# What is the benefit of casting time series models to state space form? And why are they often estimated with Kalman filters?

Tags: time-series, kalman-filter, state-space-models

For example, the R forecast package casts all exponential smoothing methods into state space form. What is the benefit besides getting a parametric prediction interval? Using the state space form has given me more accurate forecasts than just using R's default HW, why is that? Are state space models more robust to noise?

The forecast package assumes a single source of error, is it necessary to use Kalman filters in this case? What is the benefit of the Kalman filter over other methods of estimation?